# Are there any examples of viruses that have jumped from reptile to human?

Tags: virology, pathology, epidemiology, herpetology

I know that there are plenty of examples of zoonosis occurring from reptiles to humans that involve bacterial pathogens, (e.g. Salmonella) but are there any instances of viruses being transferred from reptiles to humans?

If applicable, for this question, I am only interested in reptilian viruses "jumping" from reptiles to humans, not the capacity of reptiles to serve as reservoirs for non-reptilian viruses that could potentially infect humans.

Comment: By reptiles, do you mean _non-avian Reptilia_?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification.